# How to change the color of a text in HTML using Javascript with respect to time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have created a timetable. I want the color of the subject to change during the time of the subject, according to the time automatically. But the Javascript code is not working. Please help me fix the code.

The JSFiddle link is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Xampicus/t3j1xcyk/2/#&togetherjs=vghzPt6TKP

The code for HTML and Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    Exynos
  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="style.css">
  <h4>Time Table</h4>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="time">
      <li>∀</li>
      <li>09:30-10:20</li>
      <li>10:30-11:20</li>
      <li>11:30-12:20</li>
      <li>13:10-14:00</li>
      <li>14:10-15:00</li>
      <li>15:10-16:00</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cyan">
      <li class="head" id="0">Monday</li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a href="">English Lab</a>
      </li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a>|</a>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="">ESP - II</a>
      </li>
      <li id="three">
        <a href="">Computer</a>
      </li>
      <li id="four">
        <a href="">Maths - II</a>
      </li>
      <li id="five">
        <a href="">P. E.</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="red">
      <li class="head" id="1">Tuesday</li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a href="">BEE Lab</a>
      </li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a>|</a>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="">Chemistry</a>
      </li>
      <li id="three">
        <a href="">SDP - II</a>
      </li>
      <li id="four">
        <a href="">Maths - II</a>
      </li>
      <li id="five">
        <a href="">BEE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="green">
      <li class="head" id="2">Wednesday</li>
      <li li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a href="">Computer Lab</a>
      </li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a>|</a>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="">Entre. - I</a>
      </li>
      <li id="three">
        <a href="">English</a>
      </li>
      <li id="four">
        <a href="">ESP - II</a>
      </li>
      <li id="five">
        <a href="">Eng. Mech.</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="blue">
      <li class="head" id="3">Thursday</li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a href="">Chemistry Lab</a>
      </li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a>|</a>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="">English</a>
      </li>
      <li id="three">
        <a href="">Foreign Lang.</a>
      </li>
      <li id="four">
        <a href="">Chemistry</a>
      </li>
      <li id="five">
        <a href="">Maths - II</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="yellow">
      <li class="head" id="4">Friday</li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a href="">Eng. Graphics</a>
      </li>
      <li class="highlight" id="one">
        <a>|</a>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="">SDP - II</a>
      </li>
      <li id="three">
        <a href="">Entre. - I</a>
      </li>
      <li id="four">
        <a href="">Chemistry</a>
      </li>
      <li id="five">
        <a href="">Eng. Mech.</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
function autoColor() {
    var z;
    var d = new Date();
    var count = d.getDay();
    if ((d.getHours() == 9 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes >= 30)) || (d.getHours() == 11 && (d.getMinutes() <= 30 && d.getMinutes >= 00)))
    {
      z = "one";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 11 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes >= 30)) || (d.getHours() == 12 && (d.getMinutes() <= 30 && d.getMinutes >= 00)))
    {
      z = "two";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 13 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes >= 10)) || (d.getHours() == 14 && (d.getMinutes() <= 10 && d.getMinutes >= 00)))
    {
      z = "three";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 14 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes >= 10)) || (d.getHours() == 15 && (d.getMinutes() <= 10 && d.getMinutes >= 00)))
    {
      z = "four";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 15 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes >= 10)) || (d.getHours() == 16 && (d.getMinutes() <= 10 && d.getMinutes >= 00)))
    {
      z = "five";
    }

    document.getElementById(count).getElementById(z).style.color.innerHTML = "black";
    setTimeout(autoColor,1000);

  }
  autoColor();
</script>
</html>
```

The CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Iosevka';
    src: url('Iosevka.ttf');
}

body {
    font-family: Iosevka;
    background-color: #0F0F12;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

h4 {
    margin-top: 45px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #232328;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    min-width: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
}

.flair {
  color: white;
}

ul li a {
    transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: #505050;
}

.head {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #858585;
}

.time {
    color: #858585;
}

ul.green li a:hover {
    color: #4FAE0F;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

ul.blue li a:hover {
    color: #0972D6;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

ul.red li a:hover {
    color: #ed3434;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

ul.yellow li a:hover {
    color: #edd934;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

ul.cyan li a:hover {
    color: #00E6FF;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: What is "not working"? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: Your html is invalid, you have multiple elements with the same id...

Comment: `document.getElementById(count).getElementById(z).style.color.innerHTML = "black";`  is not going to select the desired `li` element. Also, you would have to apply `color` to the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById(count)` will return, *say* `<li class="head" id="2">Wednesday</li>`.

Since you wish to select the sibling element, *say* `<li id="three"><a href="">English</a></li>` you could use:

```js
document.getElementById(count).parentElement.querySelector(`#${z}`)
```

which will select the parent element of `<li class="head" id="2">Wednesday</li>` and then search for an element with id of `z` in it's descendants.

But, you need to give the color to `a` tag inside it. So, the code finally becomes:

```js
document.getElementById(count).parentElement.querySelector(`#${z} a`).style.color = "black";
```

(*Notice the absence of innerHTML*, check this out: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML))

---

The final Javascript part becomes:

```js
function autoColor() {
    var z;
    var d = new Date(2021, 02, 03, 11, 31, 11) // new Date();
    var count = d.getDay();
    if ((d.getHours() == 9 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes() >= 30)) || (d.getHours() == 11 && (d.getMinutes() <= 30 && d.getMinutes() >= 00)))
    {
      z = "one";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 11 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes() >= 30)) || (d.getHours() == 12 && (d.getMinutes() <= 30 && d.getMinutes() >= 00)))
    {
      z = "two";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 13 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes() >= 10)) || (d.getHours() == 14 && (d.getMinutes() <= 10 && d.getMinutes() >= 00)))
    {
      z = "three";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 14 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes() >= 10)) || (d.getHours() == 15 && (d.getMinutes() <= 10 && d.getMinutes() >= 00)))
    {
      z = "four";
    }
    if ((d.getHours() == 15 && (d.getMinutes() <= 59 && d.getMinutes() >= 10)) || (d.getHours() == 16 && (d.getMinutes() <= 10 && d.getMinutes() >= 00)))
    {
      z = "five";
    }
  document.getElementById(count).parentElement.querySelector(`#${z} a`).style.color = "black";
    setTimeout(autoColor,1000);

  }
  autoColor();
```

*Note that I did `var d = new Date(2021, 02, 03, 11, 31, 11);` just to check that it's working, replace this with `new Date()`. Also, I have added few missing parenthesis.*